# Rails FastCSV import function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The current Model code in my Rails application uses "text" as key, and then updates or creates a new row depending on weather it is a duplicate or not. I am looking for a replacement code that should import all lines into the database (so no need for using text as a key, dublicate content is accepted). Anyone who know how to do this?

**routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

resources :users do
member do
  get :following, :followers
end
end
resources :sessions,        only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts,      only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships,   only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :password_resets
resources :banklines,       only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :booklines,       only: [:create, :destroy]

root to: 'static_pages#app'

post  '/upload_booklines',  to: 'booklines#upload_booklines'
match '/board',             to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',            to: 'users#new'
match '/signin',            to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout',           to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
match '/help',              to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',             to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact',           to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

**controllers/booklines_controller.rb**

```
class BooklinesController < ApplicationController

require 'csv'

def upload_booklines
 if request.post? && params[:file].present?
  infile = params[:file].read
  n, errs = 0, []

  CSV.parse(infile) do |row|
    n += 1
    next if n == 1 or row.join.blank?
    @bookline = current_user.booklines.build_from_csv(row)
    if @bookline.valid?
      @bookline.save
    else
      errs << row
    end
  end
  redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**models/bookline.rb**

```
class Bookline < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :amount, :appendix_number, :date, :text

belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy

    scope :active, where(:active => true)
    scope :latest, order('created_at desc')

  def self.build_from_csv(row)
    bookline = find_or_initialize_by_text(row[1])
    bookline.attributes ={:date => row[0], :amount => row[2], :appendix_number => row[3]}
  return bookline
  end
end
```

**Views/static_pages/app.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag('upload_booklines', :multipart => true) do %>
  <p>
     File:<br />
     <%= file_field_tag 'file' %><br />
   </p>
 <p>
   <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you're only responding to `POST` from `booklines#upload_booklines` (normally an action *should* only respond to one verb), you can modify your routes to look like this:

`post '/upload_booklines',  to: 'booklines#upload_booklines'`

And then you can remove the conditional checking if the request was a `POST`.

Now, to your question, here's what I'd do:

```
# models/bookline.rb
def self.create_from_csv(row)
    create do |b|
        b.date = row[0]
        b.text = row[1]
        b.amount = row[2]
        b.appendix_number = row[3]
    end
end

# controllers/bookslines_controller.rb
def upload_booklines
    redirect_to root_path, notice => "You must upload a .CSV file to parse." unless params[:file].present?

    CSV.parse(params[:file]) do |row|
        @bookline = current_user.booklines.create_from_csv(row)
    end
end
```

The first method, `create_from_csv` goes in the model. It will create a new record from the CSV row passed in from the controller. The second method `upload_booklines` goes in the controller. All it does is open the file and read each row into the `create_from_csv` method.

I set the attributes explicitly in `create_from_csv` because I wasn't sure if all of the data in the row goes into the model. If you're not sure, either, you should use this implementation. However, a DRYer and more Ruby-like way of doing this if all of the data maps to all of the attributes is below:

```
# models/bookline.rb
# Only use this if all of the data in the CSV row maps to attributes in the model
def self.create_from_csv(row)
    create(row.to_hash)
end
```

Essentially, we're converting the row object from the CSV parser to a hash, which can be passed directly into the create method. This is very similar to the way the standard `create` controller method works; the `params` variable is mapped by Rails from the request into a hash.

Also, as a side note, you do not need to return in Ruby explicitly. The last statement in a method is returned automatically. In your original `build_from_csv` method, you could have simply written `booklines`, without the `return` keyword. In my `create_from_csv` method, the newly created `Bookline` record will be returned, as that is what the `create` method returns.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough review!

Your code seems to be much more straight forward. I'll use it for sure. Not sure I follow with the routing issue. I will look more how to make RESTful routes. But if I remove the line "root to: 'static_pages#app" my root_path will undefined?

On the other hand, Keeping the route file gives me this error when uploading a file:

NoMethodError in BooklinesController#upload_booklines
private method `gets' called for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff0d650a838>
Rails.root: /Users/Computer/MyApp
app/controllers/booklines_controller.rb:11:in `upload_booklines'

Comment: I made a typo on the routes. I've updated the response to include the correct one. It should read `post '/upload_booklines', to: 'booklines#upload_booklines'`. Just change that one link: just from `match` to `post`. You do need to keep your `root to:` route.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. When changing the routes file, and trying to upload again, this error message gets displayed: NoMethodError in BooklinesController#upload_booklines
private method `gets' called for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb908cb6d80>
Rails.root: /Users/Computer/MyApp
app/controllers/booklines_controller.rb:11:in `upload_booklines'
Request
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"+P4kYwMng4R6vpGcVpuSCzwY2YjbTlKwTTqSTWciibA=",
 "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb908cb6d80 @original_filename="filewithsemi.csv",
 @content_type="text/csv",
[...]